# Can a JAAS login module be deployed in an EAR (on JBoss 5)?

Tags: jboss, jaas

The subject pretty much sums up the question. Normally a JAAS login module is deployed outside of an EAR application (which *uses* the authentication service, but doesn't *deploy* it).

Is it possible to deploy it in the EAR, though? There are advantages (code reuse, better integration with the app). I'm only interested in using the module for that application (in fact, that app will be the only one running in the server anyway).

Answer (score 3):

You can create a proper secure domain definition in the file with the name `xxx-jboss-beans.xml` (where `xxx` can be anything) and place that file in the `deploy` directory or inside the application (in `META-INF` directory).

Sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0">

  <application-policy xmlns="urn:jboss:security-beans:1.0" name="web-test">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code = "org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag = "required">
        <module-option name = "unauthenticatedIdentity">anonymous</module-option>
        <module-option name="usersProperties">userfile</module-option>
        <module-option name="rolesProperties">rolefile</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>

</deployment>
```

You can read more int that article: [Security Features of JBoss AS 5.1 - Part 1 - Simplified Security Domain Configuration](http://server.dzone.com/articles/security-features-jboss-510)

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible with JBoss 6.0.0. Just include your jar in the ear. Nothing else is required.
Don't know if this works with earlier versions of JBoss.

Sorry for waking the zombie :)